# Blazor hosted wasm not generating scoped identifier

Tags: .net, blazor

If I generate a hosted wasm application and attempt to use scoped CSS, the application does not generate the scoped identifiers on the HTML. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Here we see that I have a bundled css with a scoped identifier trying to make "Counter" very large.
[image: See how the css is generating]

Here we see that the HTML tag is missing its identifier.
[image: Notice how the identifier is missing]

Contents of the g.cs
[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: What have you tried? Check the generated code - in Counter.razor.g.cs, does that have the attribute? Check the browser cache has been cleared before reloading?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This is literally the hosted wasm template + a scoped css file. Like the documentation I have the UseStaticFiles and ect. I am beginning to wonder if it needs server side rendering in order to use scoped css. I also attached a picture of the g.cs. It does not have the scope identifier.

Answer (score 0):

CSS isolation was introduced in net5. Templates are using netcore3.1 server and netstandard2.1 client.